# Detect whether a Bluetooth headset is connected to Apple Watch

Tags: xcode, swift, bluetooth, watchkit, watchos-2

I was recently trying to make a WatchKit App play a background sound effect from the Apple Watch’s speakers. 
From what I experienced (correct me if I’m wrong!) this is not possible as I either need to connect a Bluetooth headset to use WKAudioFilePlayer or work with additional interface elements to play the sound (WKInterfaceMovie or presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:options:completion).

Now, instead, I would like to use WKAudioFilePlayer to have the audio played only if a Bluetooth headset is connected in order to avoid getting a „Pair a Bluetooth headset to listen to music“-alert every time no headset is available.

Is there any way to find out whether a Bluetooth Headset is connected, so I could make the audio playback conditional on that?

Comment: I'm getting the same alert on simulator. Will user see that on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Still now there is no api available to check whether bluetooth headset is paired with apple watch or not